# Error when try to use mandrill for password resetting on Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpmailer, mandrill

I try to create a password resetting system on laravel 5 and this what I do:

**1. Route.php**

```
Route::get('/password/email','Auth\PasswordController@getEmail');
Route::post('/password/email','Auth\PasswordController@postEmail');
Route::get('/password/reset/{token}','Auth\PasswordController@getReset');
Route::post('/password/reset','Auth\PasswordController@postReset');
```

**2. .env file**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mandrillapp.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=*****@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=********
```

**3. composer.json**

```
...
"require": {
....
....
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.0"
},
...
```

**4. mail.php**

```
<?php

return [
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mandrillapp.com'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
    'from' => ['address' => "****@gmail.com", 'name' => "****"],
    'encryption' => 'tls',
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'pretend' => false,
];
```

**when i try it i get a success message on the page but i don't receive any email.** 
[image: RESULT]

Answer (score 0):

Try use mandrill driver

Add your key in config/services.php and change your mail driver in .env to mandrill

See it in: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail

Comment: You are using php artisan serve? Its throw exception?